# How to set tab index for url in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

In my form I have some textboxes, to navigate from one textbox to other, I am using <kbd>tab</kbd>, but when I press <kbd>tab</kbd> the cursor navigates to the url bar,
even if I set the tabindex property to all the controls numerically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MSDN:-

> When a page is initially loaded, the first item that receives focus
>   when the Tab key is pressed is the address bar. Next, the controls on
>   the Web Forms page are tabbed to in ascending order, based on the
>   value of the TabIndex property of each control, starting with the
>   smallest positive, nonzero value.

Also, the controls who are declared with TabIndex of 0 are tabbed at the last. So, change your marup like this:-

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" TabIndex="1"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSo" runat="server" TabIndex="2"></asp:TextBox><br />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAdd" runat="server" TabIndex="3"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlArea" runat="server" TabIndex="4" class="drop">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Still, if you don't set any default focus, by default it will tab to the address bar, so to set any control's focus you can call the Focus method:-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtName.Focus();
}
```